# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided user id was not a full JID (Smack)

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I'm using `Smack` and `xmpp`  for the sending messages in the app, when I'm trying to send a picture from the phone I get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided user id was not a full JID` in the line:

```
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(id);
```

For getting id, I'm using this code:

```
String id= roster.getPresence("test2@irynas-macbook-air.local").getStanzaId();
```

What's wrong? How to get `full JID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem, the id should be in the format `"test@irynas-macbook-air.local/Irynas-MacBook-Air"`, where is `Irynas-MacBook-Air` is `resource`, so the part after "/" was important.